Handling _main() when integrating C++ static library into a C project on GHS compiler toolchain
I am trying to integrate a static library compiled with C++ into a C project. I am using the GreenHills compiler. I need some help with handling constructors and destructors since they are not recognized in C, and I encounter several linker warnings and undefined behavior while running the code on my target.
I understand that C++ performs initialization routines such as constructors in the _main function and I need to link this symbol in my C project. My problem is that I do not have a main() function in my C++ static library, whereas my C module already has one. I have tried the following so far:

Defined main() in the C++ module and kept the one in the C module.


This leads to the multiple definition of main error.


Defined main() in the C++ module and deleted the one in the C module.


This leads to unresolved symbol error for _main, suggesting that the definition of _main is missing. I do not know which GHS library contains this.


Running global constructors is the job of the C++ runtime, which runs before main is ever called.

In C++ global objects constructors should run before main, but in C there is no such thing. I don't know how this is handled in this environment, but this C/C++ mix could be a cause for problems.

Is it an option to compile and/or link everything with a C++ compiler? Otherwise you may need to hunt down how the C++ runtime is set up with that compiler.

I think the only way this works is by having a C++ main and using the C++ linker.  Create a new C++ main project, turn your existing project into a C static library.  Then using the C++ linker, link the new main project with the C++ and C static libraries .

Normally embedded systems CRTs are written to support C and C++ both at once. There's a part in the CRT for calling constructors of objects with static storage duration, but if no such constructors are present (because you are linking C for example) then nothing will be called from there. The compiler tool chain typically takes care of this.

Also there's a dumb s*** rule in C++ saying that if a function named main() exists, it must have the form int main(), even in freestanding systems. Why some CRT might decide to name main() something differently like _main. If C++ was designed with embedded systems in mind, this wouldn't have been a problem...

Anyway... if you create a new project, C or C++, is there "startup" files added to the project as default? They might be written in C but more likely assembler - could have extensions .c .asm .s etc. Peeking into those files will reveal how everything is meant to work on this tool chain.

I'm uncertain whether there are any Greenhills-specific issues here, but the usual wisdom is that you should use your C++ compiler as the linker driver for a mixed C / C++ program, including one that uses libraries built in C++.  If for some reason you can't do that then it may suffice to include the C++ standard library explicitly in your link.  Note well that none of that involves compiling C source code as C++, which you should not do.

Maybe How to use C source files in a C++ project? will help.  My answer there also works correctly for C++ source files in a C project.  The key points are (1) write the main() function in  a C++ file, and (2) link with the C++ compiler.

In rough terms, it will probably (there are cases where it isn't necessary) need to compile your main() function as C++.  But you will DEFINITELY need to link the compiled objects and libraries as a C++ program, to ensure that startup code need for C++ programs (e.g. machinery to call constructors of static variables) is present in the executable and executed.
